# Dual form in bibtex style file

Tags: bibtex, programming

I'm writing a thesis in my language that, apart from singular and plural forms, has the dual form. I'm using bibtex and I'm having problems with translating the .bst style properly to support the dual form.

How should I modify the following code to satisfy my needs?

```
FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >
    { ", editors" * }
    { ", editor" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what's a "dual form"?

Comment: @Mico Some languages have singular, dual and plural. Czech has dual, IIRC, for things that are considered as a pair.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, have a look at the [FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq), particularly to [How do I ask question here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) in order to make your contributions to the site even more valuable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" } 
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >
        { editor num.names$ #2 > { ", editors" * } { ", two editors" * } if$ }
        { ", editor" * }
      if$
    }
  if$   
}
```

Change "two editors" with your dual form.